# Usar robocopy con filtro de nombre de archivo

Tags: script, cmd, batch, msdos

Necesito copiar unos archivos con nombre largo desde un directorio origen hacia un destino determinado. Pero dependiendo de los últimos 8 caracteres del nombre del archivo (sin considerar la extensión) se deben almacenar en una carpeta diferente.

por ejemplo tengo archivos con estos nombres:

```
20191210,163958414,PA008A021SE002A021,**SP019A021SE002A021**.cfg
20201005,212914881,PA009A021SE002A021,**SP024A021SE002A021**.dat
20201006,212914881,PA009A021SE002A021,**SP024A021SE002A021**.cfg
```

Para el caso los dos últimos archivos se deben guardar en una misma carpeta, pero que será distinta a la carpeta donde se debe almacenar el primer archivo.

He intentado usar un if, pero tal vez robocopy pueda filtrar por nombre de forma más fácil aunque no lo sé, es primera vez que utilizo robocopy.

He intentado esto, pero claramente no funciona. Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda en este asunto.

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\origen"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
    set "name=%%a"
    if %%a:~39,-4 EQU SP019A021SE002A021 (robocopy "%cd%" "C:\destino1\!name:~39,-4!\OSCILOGRAFIAS" "%%a")
)
popd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es era más sencillo de lo que imaginaba. Espero la respuesta le sirva a alguien como yo que no es del rubro de la programación

```
echo off
robocopy C:\origen\ C:\destino_1\P004L078SE007L078\folder1 *P004L078SE007L078*.* /E /Z /COPY:DT /MIR /TEE /LOG+:sincrolog_P004L078SE007L078.txt
exit
```